# How to adjust the TableView height when one of the item got deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Initially i wanted to create a **UITableView** which has a dynamic height according to its content size and followed a question of **stackoverflow** to overcome the situation. So what implemented after going through that question:

```
func autoAdjustToTableView(){

        numberTableView.frame = CGRect(x: numberTableView.frame.origin.x, y: numberTableView.frame.origin.y, width: numberTableView.frame.size.width, height: numberTableView.contentSize.height)

    }
```

And in the answer of that question it was suggested that i should call this thing from **viewDidAppear** and also from **viewDidLayoutSubViews** and also he called

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

*So my first question why would i have to code in my* **viewDidLayoutSubviews** ??

Though its working fine until the moment i am removing an item from the tableView and calling the same function is not getting me the dynamic change. This is where i m removing it:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
        { action -> Void in

            return

        })
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive)
        { action -> Void in

            self.numberArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.autoAdjustToTableView()
            self.numberTableView.reloadData()

        })
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

*What needs to be done to change its height at removing item ??*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to call reloadData to change cells in tableView. The you need to call autoAdjustToTable view to change the height.

```
        self.numberArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.numberTableView.reloadData()
        self.autoAdjustToTableView()
```

Comment: When you call reloadData you are telling tableview to create its content again. So you should first reloadData then calculate the height of the tableview base on its content.